# Need to extract VSI and Bare Metal usage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have to find out the cpu, memory, network, and storage usage of VSIs and Bare Metal devices. Are there any SoftLayer APIs to retrieve this information?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hardware you can only see the use of bandwidth, only in vm can you get the cpu, memory usage.

For get the usage VSI, try following the example:

**VirtualGuest**

```
htps://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_VirtualGuest/123456/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,metricTrackingObject]
```

The 123456 data, you choose the id instance (Hardware, VSI)
after use in the next request:

**Method POST**

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/987654321/getSummaryData
```

The 987654321 data, you  should change with metricTrackingObject id data got in the last request

**Body**

```
{
    "parameters": [
        "2019-11-04T19:06:11-06:00 America/dallas",
        "2019-11-07T19:06:11-16:00 America/dallas", [{
            "keyName": "CPU0",
            "summaryType": "max"
        },{
            "keyName": "MEMORY_USAGE",
            "summaryType": "max"
        }],
        600

    ]
}
```

You choose the data time to get th memory, cpu usage.

**Reference**

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/#metricTrackingObject
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/getSummary/

I hope it helps you

Comment: I tried to perform the getSummary Data method and got the following response.  RC 500 with content of {"error":"Invalid type\\/s was\\/were passed.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Metric_Tracking_Object_InvalidTypeRequest"}      I tried to find what the valid types were, but to no avail.

Comment: The content sent on the request is   {
        "parameters": [
           "2019-11-15T00:00:00-0500 America/New_York",
           "2019-11-15T23:59:59-0500 America/New_York", [
             {
               "keyName": "CPU0",
               "summaryType": "max"
             },
             {
               "keyName": "MEMORY_USAGE",
               "summaryType": "max"
             }
           ],
           600

        ]
      }

Comment: I issued this URL https://a
pi.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/47908578/getMetricDa
taTypes to get the data types.  I noticed the summaryType was average for CPU0 and MEMORY_USAGE, so I changed the parameter content summaryType to average and got the same error result.